# C3P0 deadlock with Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, c3p0

I am facing the following error and I am having a very difficult time debugging where this issue is coming from. I have the following 2 session factories:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory1"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${db.driver}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${db.jdbcurl2}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${db.username2}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${db.password2}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">6</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">3000</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql" >false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql" >false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" >update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory2"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" primary="true">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${db.driver}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${db.jdbcurl}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${db.username}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${db.password}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">6</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">3000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql" >false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql" >false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" >update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And the following connection data:

> db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>
> hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
>
> db.jdbcurl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XXXXautoReconnect=true&allowMultiQueries=true
>   db.username=XXXX
>
> db.password=YYYY
>
> db.jdbcurl2=jdbc:mysql://XXXXX-cluster.XXXXXXXX.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/XXXX?autoReconnect=true&allowMultiQueries=true
>
> db.username2=XXXX
>
> db.password2=YYYY

This is the error message I get from the logs:

```
    2017-10-30 12:16:25 WARN  ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:743 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@6cf38f72 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
2017-10-30 12:16:25 WARN  ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:759 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@6cf38f72 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
    Managed Threads: 3
    Active Threads: 3
    Active Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@5371f5ab
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqsmig9ruavayon79lc0|319cb4da]-HelperThread-#0
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@12e0b3c5
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqsmig9ruavayon79lc0|319cb4da]-HelperThread-#2
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@2b726e6f
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqsmig9ruavayon79lc0|319cb4da]-HelperThread-#1
    Pending Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@432689e8
Pool thread stack traces:
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqsmig9ruavayon79lc0|319cb4da]-HelperThread-#0,5,RMI Runtime]
        java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
```

I tried setting c3p0.max_statements to 0 as well as many other things none of which worked so I am seeking for your help if you know how to resolve this issue.

**I think it is worth mentioning that everything used to work fine when I was using 2 data sources locally. The minute I created a new RDS instance and changed the jdbcurl url to the rds one, I got the above mentioned error message..**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that attempts to your RDS database are hanging -- neither failing with an Exception, nor succeeding and providing and Exception, just hanging. I've experienced Connection hangs on AWS when I had not properly configured my instance to accept connections from my client. That's likely your problem.

One way way to test and debug this is with a simple test program, something like

```
import java.sql.*;

public static void main(String[] argv) {
  try {
    DriverManager.getConnection("dbc:mysql://XXXXX-cluster.XXXXXXXX.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/XXXX?autoReconnect=true&allowMultiQueries=true","XXXX","YYYY").close();
    System.out.println("Successfully acquired and closed a Connection.");
  }
  catch ( Exception e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

If you have access to a REPL of some sort, then just try

```
    DriverManager.getConnection("dbc:mysql://XXXXX-cluster.XXXXXXXX.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/XXXX?autoReconnect=true&allowMultiQueries=true","XXXX","YYYY").close();
```

When this succeeds from the machine from which you intend to run your application, so probably too will your application.

Comment: this is indeed where the problem is and I have been debugging it for a day now and still cannot identify why this is happening. I have been able to connect to my RDS instance through Sequel Pro and MySQLWorkbench but just not from my java program...my connection url is in the exact same format as yours but for some reason it is timing out..

Comment: EDIT: I had to create a reverse tunnel and change the url string to 127.0.0.1 as well as the port to the one of the reverse tunnel to make it work locally.